# Flattening JSON API response in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, javascript-objects

JSON Object returned from API Response:

```
{3 items
    "total_reviews":574
    "stars_stat":{5 items
    "1":"2%"
    "2":"1%"
    "3":"3%"
    "4":"8%"
    "5":"85%"
    }
    "result":[10 items
    0:{9 items
    "id":"R3BWKTLO7CM3Y9"
    "asin":{...}2 items
    "review_data":"Reviewed in the United States on April 15, 2022"
    "date":{2 items
    "date":"April 15, 2022"
    "unix":1649988000
    }
    "name":"Sally N."
    "rating":5
    "title":"Great alcohol !"
    "review":"Great products"
    "verified_purchase":true
    }
    1:{...}9 items
    2:{...}9 items
    3:{...}9 items
    4:{...}9 items
    5:{...}9 items
    6:{...}9 items
    7:{...}9 items
    8:{...}9 items
    9:{...}9 items
    ]
```

I've tried various approaches but keep getting stuck implementing the approach or realizing it's wrong so I just commented out all the stuff I tried.  I first tried to just select for a specific information in the response object and store it in a variable, then passing the info to a record object that matches the CSV headers I need, so I can write it to a file, however, couldn't make it work iteratively in a loop for the different key/value pairs I need.  Then I read about an inbuilt json object function that lets you loop through a json object based on the keys `object.keys`, values `object.values`, or both `object.entries`, but I have nested key/values and some of the information I need is nested.  So I think the solution is to figure out how to flatten the JSON object into just the key-values I need, and that is what I'm seeking help with.  Ultimately trying to write this info to a csv file.

I need the following fields: customer name, product name, SKU, review content, star rating, and time and date created

My Code I've tried:

```
const axios = require("axios");
const converter = require("json-2-csv");
const fs = require("fs");
const moment = require('moment');
const createCsvWriter = require('csv-writer').createObjectCsvWriter;

const csvWriter = createCsvWriter({
  path: './ProductReviews.csv',
  header: ['asin', 'name', 'review', 'rating'].map((item) => ({ id: item, title: item }))
})

const options = {
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'https://amazon23.p.rapidapi.com/reviews',
  params: {asin: 'B00DUGMVC6', sort_by: 'recent', page: '1', country: 'US'},
  headers: {
    'X-RapidAPI-Key': 'redacted',
    'X-RapidAPI-Host': 'redacted'
  }
};


    axios.request(options).then(function (response) {
        console.log(response.data);
      // for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++  ) {
      // let name = response.data.result[i].name;
      // let content = response.data.result[i].review;
      // let rating = response.data.result[i].rating;
      // let date = response.data.result[i].date.date
      
      // let momentvar = moment(date, 'MMM DD, YYYY').format();
    
      // const records = [
      //   {
      //     customername: name, productname: 'Isopropyl Alcohol 99.9%', sku: 'B00DUGMVC6', reviewcontent: content, starrating: rating, timeanddate: date
      //   }
      // ]
    
      // for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(response.data)) {
      //   console.log(key, value);
      // }    
    
        // try { 
        //    csvWriter.writeRecords(response.data.result[0]);
        // } catch (error) {
        //   console.log(error);
        // }
    
        // converter.json2csv(response.data, (err, csv) => {
        //     if (err) {
        //       throw err;
        //     }
    
        //     fs.writeFileSync('todos.csv', csv);
        // })
    
      // csvWriter.writeRecords(records)       // returns a promise
      //   .then(() => {
      //       console.log('...Done');
      //   });
        
      // }
    
      // var response = JSON.parse(response);
      // console.log(response);
    
      // csvWriter.writeRecords(response.data)
    
        // converter.json2csv(response.data, (err, csv) => {
        //     if (err) {
        //         throw err;
        //     }
            
        //     console.log(csv);
        // })
    
    }).catch(function (error) {
        console.error(error);
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just skimming [css-writer documentation](https://github.com/ryu1kn/csv-writer), it looks like the package wants two js objects: one describing the header, and another array of records who's keys match the ids given in the header object.

From what I can make of the OP's input object, the transform is straight-forward.  The only unclear bit is what should be written for the `asin` key, which is described in the question as an object, but not elaborated further.

Here's a demo of the transform to csv-writer params. In it, we just stringify the `asin` object...

```js
const data = {
  "total_reviews":574,
  "stars_stat":{
    "1":"2%",
    "2":"1%",
    "3":"3%",
    "4":"8%",
    "5":"85%"
  },
  "result":[
    {
      "id":"R3BWKTLO7CM3Y9",
      "asin":{ 
        "original":"B00DUGMVC6",
        "variant":"B00DUGMVC6"
      }, 
      "review_data":"Reviewed in the United States on April 15, 2022",
      "date":{
        "date":"April 15, 2022",
        "unix":1649988000
      },
      "name":"Sally N.",
      "rating":5,
      "title":"Great alcohol !",
      "review":"Great products",
      "verified_purchase":true
    },
    // more like this
  ]
}

const result = data.result;
// OP should replace the previous line with const result = response.data.result;


const header = ['asin', 'name', 'review', 'rating'].map((item) => ({ id: item, title: item }))
const records = result.map(({ asin: { original, variant } , name, date: { date }, review, rating }) => {
  date = new Date(date).toISOString();
  return { original, variant, name, review, rating, date };
});

console.log(header, records);

// // OP should replace the previous line with:
// const csvWriter = createCsvWriter({
//   path: './ProductReviews.csv',
//   header: header
// })
// csvWriter.writeRecords(records)
```

**edit**
Calling and writing several pages might look something like the following. Notes: (1) from reading, I learned that `asin` is like a product id, probably invariant over all reviews, (2) reasonably low volume (see if it performs, then consider streaming if it doesn't), (3) guessing that no records returned for a page means we're done.

```
async function getReviewPage(asin, page, csvWriter) {
  const options = {
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'https://amazon23.p.rapidapi.com/reviews',
    params: {asin, sort_by: 'recent', page: page+'', country: 'US'},
    headers: {
      'X-RapidAPI-Key': 'redacted',
      'X-RapidAPI-Host': 'redacted'
    }
  };
  const response = await axios.request(options);
  const result = response.data.result;
  
  const records = result.map(({ asin: { original, variant } , name, date: { date }, review, rating }) => {
    date = new Date(date).toISOString();
    return { original, variant, name, review, rating, date };
  });
  if (records.length) await csvWriter.writeRecords(records)
  return records.length === 0; 
}

async function getAllReviews(asin) {
  const header = ['asin', 'name', 'review', 'rating'].map((item) => ({ id: item, title: item }))
  const csvWriter = createCsvWriter({
    path: './ProductReviews.csv',
    header: header
  });
  let done = false;
  let page = 1;
  while (!done) {
    done = await getReviewPage(asin, page++, csvWriter);
  }
  return page-1
}

// test it with
getAllReviews('myASIN').then(pagesWritten => console.log(`wrote ${pagesWritten} pages`);

// run it one of two ways:
async function getAllReviewsForAllProducts(asinArray) {
  // in parallel, though you might get throttled by the service...
  return await Promise.all(asinArray.map(getAllReviews));

  // OR sequentially
  for (let asin of asinArray) {
    await getAllReviews(asin)
  }
}
```

Comment: `"result":[10 items
0:{9 items
"id":"R3BWKTLO7CM3Y9"
"asin":{2 items
"original":"B00DUGMVC6"
"variant":"B00DUGMVC6"
}
"review_data":"Reviewed in the United States on April 15, 2022"
"date":{2 items
"date":"April 15, 2022"
"unix":1649988000
}
"name":"Sally N."
"rating":5
"title":"Great alcohol !"
"review":"Great products"
"verified_purchase":true
}`

That's the expanded field for ASIN and Date.

Comment: I also need to convert the date into ISO 8601 format

Comment: I just need the value for original and the value for date.  If I use `JSON.stringify()` that includes both values, which I don't want.  Otherwise this answer is very close to the what I'm trying to achieve.  @danh

Comment: @DanielTaki, edited to deeply destructure the asin and date objects, and to convert the date to ISO.

Comment: that worked perfectly.  Is there a way I can traverse the pages in the original GET request endpoint and append the csv each time with the new rows until there isn't any data left in result object?

Comment: Sure, sounds like a different question. Can you post and provide me a link here?  Please be sure to explain how the asin value is produced initially and on subsequent calls.  Please me sure to indicate how the API signals no more records.  From the CSV docs, it looks like they have a streaming mode if the api delivers many large results, and the simpler mode that you're using.  Please indicate in the question about how much data is in each page and about how many pages.

Comment: I've reached my question limit... This is the first question I've asked in at least a yea too.

Comment: I had never heard of this. Just read about it to learn that you get the ban for providing too many poorly-received questions or answers.  Have you had a lot closed?  Your profile looks perfectly good to my (untrained) eye. I wonder if it's a glitch related to the site outage we just experienced? Can you retry?

Comment: cleared my browser cache and still takes me to a page when I try to ask a question which states,

`You have reached your question limit
Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. See the Help Center to learn more.`

Comment: Do I need to use a different module to achieve to write to a stream or is csv-writer capable of that.

Comment: From the docs, it looks like there's a stream api built in, but no example provided.  Google should help there.  I'm puzzled by your problem posting.  (here's where I read about it https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th).  Have you run afoul somehow?

Comment: I had a few posts when I was just starting to learn stackoverflow and ask questions that were deleted.  Usually involved my not understanding how to properly phrase a question (sometime half the problem is not understanding the question to ask).  I included a imgur link to the deleted questions, but its from a long while back. 

https://imgur.com/a/Yk5Jqxc

Comment: Anyway, @DanielTaki, I edited to suggest how to call for multiple pages sequentially (lots of caveats in terms of guessing how the API works, and certainly never tested).  Best of luck

Comment: That worked perfectly! Last bit lol I need to understand is calling the `getAllreviews()` function multiple times, and each time, appending the result to the same csv file without rewriting it.

Something like

`getAllReviews('B08GTSZ741')`  


`getAllReviews('B08GTSZ741')`

Comment: @DanielTaki, I suggested two ways to call it.

Comment: Awesome I couldn't get the second variation to work 

`for (let asin of asinArray) {
    await getAllReviews(asin)
  }` 

but I did get the first variation to work.  

I changed the first variation a little too to:

`for (key in dict) {
 await getAllReviews(key)
}`

I had defined a dict object that mapped the ASIN/SKU in key/value pairs, however, kept getting this error when running.

`await is only valid in async function`

First variation is solid and gave me the output.  There's so many concepts here I don't grasp where should I start to understand how you solved all this.